# segmentation fault in BST c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I have created a binary search tree, in which i have been following a tutorial online (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0FDBGbf42Q : PaulProgramming). My code is practically the same as the code in the tutorial but when I run my main, I get a segmentation fault. I cannot figure out why. If anybody can just point out where my error is that would be so greatly appreciated. And yes, sorry about the using namespace std, I will change everything appropriately after I get this running.

BST.h

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

class BST{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };

    node* root;

    void addLeafPrivate(int Data, node* ptr);
    void printInOrderPrivate(node* ptr);

public:
    BST();
    node* createLeaf(int Data);
    void addLeaf(int Data);
    void printInOrder();

};
#endif
```

BST.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "BST.h"

using namespace std;

BST::BST(){
    root = NULL;
}



BST::node* BST::createLeaf(int Data){
    node* leaf = new node;
    leaf->data = Data;
    leaf->left = NULL;
    leaf->right = NULL;

    return leaf;
}

void BST::addLeafPrivate(int Data, node* ptr){
    if(root = NULL)
        root = createLeaf(Data);

    else if(Data < ptr->data){
        if(ptr->left != NULL)
            addLeafPrivate(Data, ptr->left);
        else
            ptr->left= createLeaf(Data);
    }

    else if(Data > ptr->data){
        if(ptr->right != NULL)
            addLeafPrivate(Data, ptr->right);
        else
            ptr->right= createLeaf(Data);
    }

    else
        cout<< "The key " << Data << "already exist in the Binary Search Tree" << endl;
}

void BST::printInOrderPrivate(node* ptr){
    if(root != NULL){
        cout<< ptr->data << " " <<endl;
        if(ptr->left != NULL)
            printInOrderPrivate(ptr->left);
        if(ptr->right != NULL)
            printInOrderPrivate(ptr->right);
    }
    else
        cout<<"Binary Search Tree is empty " << endl;
}

void BST::addLeaf(int Data){
    addLeafPrivate(Data, root); 
}

void BST::printInOrder(){
    printInOrderPrivate(root);
}
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "BST.cpp"

int main(){
    BST tree;
    tree.addLeaf(2);
    tree.addLeaf(5);
    tree.addLeaf(10);
    tree.addLeaf(0);

    tree.printInOrder();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `bst.h` and `main.cpp` file are identical. I assume that's a typo in which case you should show us your *real* `bst.h`.

Comment: How come you include bst.cpp in your main.cpp, is it typo ?

Comment: oops my mistake, let me edit

Comment: Thank you guys for your time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in addLeafPrivate you do if(root = NULL) instead of if(root == NULL)

Comment: I knew it was going to be something like this! I just needed another eye. Thank you so much. What a rookie mistake.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, I apologize for the waste of time. But you helped me out very much. I have have been searching for the bug for hours more if it wasn't for the stackoverflow community.